# how to convert to string Option

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I want the following output to match with a city name. But what I want the output to represent is `Some "city"` not just `"city"`. How would I implement this in the code? And also for "total" to be `None` but not "None" as I have currently have it. Adding `None` and `Some` before the `c + "city"` results in errors.

```
let listStackOverFlowExample = ["Kansas","Iowa"]

let cityAddCity (city:string) =
    | "total" - > "None"
    | _ -> city + " City"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The answer

You had the right idea by adding `Some` before the `city + " City"` expression, but you didn't know about F#'s precedence rules. By F#'s syntax rules, `Some x` (where `x` is anything) acts like function application, and function application has the highest precedence. So `Some city + " City"` is treated not like `Some (city + " City")`, but rather like `(Some city) + " City"`. The former would be valid, but the latter is not valid, because that's a `string option` type added to a `string` type.

All you need to do here is to write your second case as `Some (city + " City")` and you'll have the result you were looking for:

```
let cityAddCity (city:string) =
    | "total" - > None
    | _ -> Some (city + " City")
```

#### Why is it like that?

If you're wondering why function application has the highest precedence in F#, causing you to have to add parentheses after `Some` in your function, consider a situation like the following:

```
let double x = x * 2
let triple x = x * 3

let result = double 5 + triple 2
```

What value would you expect `result` to have? 16? Or 22? Personally, looking at that expression I would expect it to have the value 16, and I would be very surprised if `result` had the value 22. If function application did *not* have high precedence, and it actually had lower precedence than addition, then the value of `result` would have been calculated like this:

```
let result = double 5 + triple 2
let result = double (5 + triple 2)
let result = double (5 + 6)
let result = double 11
let result = 22
```

But in fact, function application *does* have the highest precedence in F#, so `result` is actually calculated like this:

```
let result = double 5 + triple 2
let result = 10 + 6
let result = 16
```

This precedence rule is intuitively, and obviously, correct in the case of the `double 5 + triple 2` expression. In the `Some (city + " City")` expression, it's not immediately and intuitively obvious why you need to add the parentheses, but it's due to the same rule. Just keep in mind that in F#, function application takes precedence over *everything* else, and if you get an error like this one again, you'll probably be able to remember that the answer is to add explicit parentheses.